# Can not run the code of this repository - NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, python-embedding

I am trying to run this [code](https://github.com/sb1992/NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-) - Automatic Labelling of Topics with Neural Embeddings

The problem is that they did not mention what versions they used for the libraries and tools they used. Sadly, not even which Python version they have used.

I have started by trying to run the pre-trained models, I have followed their instructions but I got the following error, please see the following  screenshot:

[image]

I am using Python 3.11.1, and I used pip to get gensim.

I really need help with this one, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The code in that repository appears to have been last touched around November 2016, so in the absence of properly-documented requirements, you could try versions of Python, Gensim, Numpy, & Pandas that were current then.

Looking just at the [Gensim release history](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases?page=4), the absolute latest Gensim it could have been based on would be [0.13.3, released October 16, 2016](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/0.13.3) – though of course in the absence of clarity from the original authors, it could also be an earlier release.

The latest Python that Gensim supported at the time was 3.5 – though in the absence of clarity from the original authors, i's possible they were using a Python 2.x like Python 2.7 as well.

If you decide to try to reproduce their outdated setup, you can likely find the then-current versions of other libraries, as well. I would strongly suggest using virtual environments to isolate whatever project-specific Python, & libraries, you're testing for this purpose - the `miniconda` approach can work well, as it even lets you vary the Python interpreter.

However, building on such a partially documented & not-recently-updated project may involve additional frustrations and risks. The older versions of Python & libraries may be missing fixes – including security fixes – that are important, and may be hard to integrate with any other more modern code you hope to use.

Instead of re-creating an outdated environment, you may want to try to migrate the code, and any old saved pretrained models, to work with current libraries. That will require understanding the code's intent, & adapting each individual source-of-failure one-by-one. It may only require a few lines-of-code changes – if any. (The `NETL-Automatic-Topic-Labelling-/` project appears to be only around 400 total lines of code, and at least with regard to Gensim, most necessary changes to older breaking conventions are described in a [Migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4) reference guide.)

If you need to use its old pretrained models, the larger challenge may be migrating those model forward into forms matching current libraries. There, a strategy that *may* work is (a) find the latest version of Gensim that can load a working version of the target model; (b) upon confirming its operation, re-`.save()` the model from that version; (c) repeat, finding the new latest version of Gensim that can load the re-saved model, until being able to load and save the model-of-interest from current Gensim.

I'd especially focus on Gensim versions like 2.3.0 (last of the 2.x series), 3.2.0 (last version before a major refactoring of `Word2Vec`- & `Doc2Vec`- related classes), and 3.8.3 (last version of 3.x series & last version to support Python 2) as potential "stepping stones" to load-and-resave an old model up to current version (4.3.0 as of December 2022) compatibility.

Comment: I am running a group of experiments using the recommendations you gave me.
Experiment 1: Gensim 0.13.3 + Python 2.7.9 - outcome: could not install any library including upgrading pip, after long research people said to upgrade to a newer Python
Using the this link: https://pypi.org/project/gensim/0.13.3/ I found out what Python versions work with Gensim 0.13.3 (Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5). This led me to my second Experiment, please se below.

Comment: Experiment 2: Python 3.5.0 + Gensim 0.13.3. I was able to get the recommended libraries (hopefully I got the correct versions). Now, I am getting this: ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'. A guy in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368524/importerror-cannot-import-name-type-when-importing-gensim said that I should upgrade to Python 3.6!

Comment: This ImportError: cannot import name 'Type' happens on the "import gensim" instruction.
Any help is greaaatly apreciated as I really need this to work.

Comment: Alas, those are the kinds of headaches that are common using 6+ year-old code that's not been updated/maintained by its original authors. If for some reason you feel you must use Gensim-0.13.3, you should stick to a Python it supports, like a Python 3.5.x. But exactly Python-3.5.0 will be the oldest/buggiest of all Python 3.5.x options. Something like Python-3.5.7, the most-fixed-up of the 3.5.x series, will be a better bet – & *might* fix your `Type` issue.

Comment: But there will likely be other issues trying to use such an outdated software stack, so I'd really recommend (a) to the extent you need to use that old project's *code*, understand it and make whatever chnages are necessary for it to work using current Python/Gensim/Pandas/Numpy/etc; (b) don't use its ancient pretrained model at all, instead training something new, on texts relevant to your current project.